# Why does my computer startup again when suspended?

Tags: 10.04, suspend

the whole point of suspending a computer is to make it cool off and be quiet. But my computer starts up just as it get's quiet, it's really annoying! 
My computer is a [Asus 1201n](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1201N_Seashell/) and I'm running 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some computers have "wakeup" events in their BIOS.  For example, my computer (it is not a Asus) has "wakeup from LAN, wakeup from mouse, and wakeup from keyboard".  I have these disabled.

Another computer I have has a "S1" or "S3" setting for a 'sleep' setting in the BIOS.  I have this set as "S3".

Check your bios to see if you have something similar and change some settings.